¿cómo implementar Stripe como pasarela de pagos en Django?
Estoy probando implementar Stripe en un sitio en Django de una tienda online, pero tengo el problema de que los productos están alojados en una base de datos, pero no los quiero publicar directamente en la página de Stripe.
He estado investigando como hacer esto, pero los ejemplos que me salen incluso en la documentación es agregándolos a la página manualmente, pero mis productos ya tienen su modelo en mi base de datos que también tengo con Django.
¿Alguna idea?
Saludos.
